# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied in Plone 4.1.4 zeo with collective.recipe.filestorage

Tags: plone

I have a plone 4.1.4 "UnifiedInstaller" zeo install on debian 5 and I want to use multiple Data.fs with collective.recipe.filestorage.

I get this error when I start the zeo server:
`IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/intranetcfa/intranetcfa/var/filestorage/vanilla/Data.fs.lock'`

My buildout:

```
parts =
    filestorage
    ...

[filestorage]
recipe=collective.recipe.filestorage
blob-storage = var/blobstorage-%(fs_part_name)s
location = var/filestorage/%(fs_part_name)s/Data.fs
parts =
    vanilla
```

which results in zeo.conf :

```
<filestorage vanilla>
    path /home/intranetcfa/intranetcfa/var/filestorage/vanilla/Data.fs
    blob-dir /home/intranetcfa/intranetcfa/var/blobstorage-vanilla
</filestorage>
```

and zope.conf :

```
<zodb_db vanilla>
    cache-size 5000
    <zeoclient>
      blob-dir /home/intranetcfa/intranetcfa/var/blobstorage-vanilla
      shared-blob-dir on
      server 127.0.0.1:8102
      storage vanilla
      name vanilla_zeostorage
      var /home/intranetcfa/intranetcfa/parts/client1/var
      cache-size 30MB

    </zeoclient>
    mount-point /vanilla
</zodb_db>
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/intranetcfa/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/ZEO/runzeo.py", line 405, in <module>
main()
  File "/home/intranetcfa/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/ZEO/runzeo.py", line 402, in main
s.main()
  File "/home/intranetcfa/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/ZEO/runzeo.py", line 158, in main
self.open_storages()
  File "/home/intranetcfa/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/ZEO/runzeo.py", line 207, in open_storages
self.storages[opener.name] = opener.open()
  File "/home/intranetcfa/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/config.py", line 177, in open
return FileStorage(config.path, **options)
  File "/home/intranetcfa/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/FileStorage/FileStorage.py", line 125, in __init__
self._lock_file = LockFile(file_name + '.lock')
  File "/home/intranetcfa/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.lockfile-1.0.0-py2.6.egg/zc/lockfile/__init__.py", line 73, in __init__
fp = open(path, 'w+')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/intranetcfa/intranetcfa/var/filestorage/vanilla/Data.fs.lock'
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is a http://serverfault.com type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `var/filestorage/vanilla` directory cannot be written to by the user your ZEO server runs as, or you previously ran ZEO as a different user and the `Data.fs.lock` file it created is not writeable by the current user.

Fix this by adjusting the permissions on that directory, or if the `.lock` file exists, the lock file itself.

Comment: This usually happen when you mix user installation with buildout run by root. It would be cool if the buildout script detect it and switch to user to run the script.